# How to filter out/in from GroupLayer (hide/show)

Tags: leaflet, filter

Assuming I have the following groupLayer:

```
var myGroupLayer = new L.layerGroup();
```

and I add it to my map:

```
myGroupLayer.addTo(map);
```

somewhere in my app I add some layer to myGroupLayer like:

```
myOptions= {
           
          "dashArray": [
            10,
            20
          ],
          "weight": 2, 
          "pulseColor": "#FFFFFF",
          "paused": false,
          "reverse": false,   
          "id":id,
          "show_on_map":true
        }

var flight= L.polyline.antPath(coords, myOptions);
myGroupLayer.addLayer(flight);
```

Now, at some point I change the show_on_map field to false and I wish **not to show** them on the map. How can I fiter them out? I have tried to initially set the myGroupLayer with

```
myGroupLayer .setFilter(f=>{
    return f.properties['options']['show_on_map'] === true; 
});
```

but it didnt work out.

Comment: From which Leaflet plugin does `L.polyline.antPath(coords, myOptions)` call comes from?

Comment: @TomazicM I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/rubenspgcavalcante/leaflet-ant-path

Comment: Bur regardless of some possible specific methods for this type of a layer you can always simply remove it from map with `flight.remove()`.

Comment: but later, I may need it. In other words, I wish to hide some of them temporarily.

Comment: Ups, sorry, I overlooked it's part of a group layer. So to remove it from the map, the call is `myGroupLayer.removeLayer(flight)`. To put it back on the map, you again add it to the group: `myGroupLayer.addLayer(flight)`.

Comment: :-) yes, but with this strategy I'll need to save the flight somewhere (list, session etc). I don't want to do that, what I want is to filter in/out from the layer and avoid the push to another variable.

Comment: Sorry, I'm no fan of chats. And by the way, I'm afraid that described solution is the only one you have.